# Glassmorphism TabBar - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to give it a little bit of blur or something similar to Glassmorphism style so the color doesn't look so solid, I tried this:

```
.onAppear {
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
}
```

and even though I can see somehow a littttte bit of the background as blured, it the background of the tabbar, it still looks too solid. How can I apply some color to blend with the background of the view and once the view passes through the TabBar it gets blur, like the view doesn't override the background of the tabbar.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Some other things I've tried:

```
// This doesn't work, don't know why
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "tabBarBackground")

// It says: Value of type 'UITabBarAppearance' has no member 'opacity'
.opacity(0.1)
```

Pd: I'm using iOS 15

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to create two different `UITabBarAppearance` objects, one for `standardAppearance` (when content is scrolled under the tab bar) and one for `scrollEdgeAppearance` (when no content is under the tab bar).

I think this configuration creates the effect you want:

```
.onAppear {
    let standardAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    standardAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = standardAppearance
    
    let scrollEdgeAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    scrollEdgeAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = scrollEdgeAppearance
}
```

You could also set the standard appearance’s background color:

```
let standardAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
standardAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
standardAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "tabBarBackground")
UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = standardAppearance
```

Or customize the blur effect:

```
let standardAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
standardAppearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
standardAppearance.backgroundEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)
UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = standardAppearance
```

If you want customization beyond that, you’ll probably need to build your own tab bar view.