# SwiftUI Tab Bar inconsistent BackgroundColor

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

Here's my view

```
struct StackCheck: View {
    var rows = [Int](0...20)
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            List {
                ForEach(rows, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Words")
            }
            
            ZStack {
                Color.blue.opacity(0.4)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                Text("Check")
            }
            .tabItem {
                Text("Check")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i tap on List view and scroll to the bottom, the Tab Bar background becomes **transparent**.

If after that i tap on `Check View`, the Tab Bar background is still absolutely transparent, which makes tab bar labels hard to read.

However, if i don't scroll to the bottom of the `List View`, tab bar background has a **semitrasparent** color and a divider on top.

If then i switch to `Check View`, tab bar labels are easy to read.

**So my question is**: How do i modify tab bar, so it doestn't change it's background opacity?

I'd really like it to have this divider and semitransparent background every time.

[image: LabelView is scrolled to the bottom]

[image: LabelView is not scrolled to the bottom]

Comment: replace `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` with `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69329230/glassmorphism-tabbar-swiftui

Comment: The solution in the link is exactly what i needed, thanks!